# How to regulate a resonant converter at no load?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I am designign a high voltage power supply using the half bridge LCC topology (NOT LLC), but I suppose it relates to both.

When operating at full load, the high voltage output settles at the desired value before 1ms. However, when I replace the load resistors with current sources with DC value = 0mA to simulate no load conditions, I am unable to get the output voltage to settle. I have attached a screen grab showing this - it reaches the final voltage but then fluctuates/drops.

Nominally I switch at 500kHz. At the moment, I am sweeping the switching frequency DOWN and observing the output voltage (blue traces). It is to my understanding as the load current decreases, the switching frequency reduces.

Are there any ways to calculate the switching frequency for the no load condition? I know it is a function of the load resistance, but in my case this would have to be in the high MegOhm range since my feedback resistor is 100MEG.

Any advice appreciated. Also see attached resonant current waveform and schematic. Input voltage shown as AC but it's actually 270VDC.

[image: VOUT]
[image: RES. CURRENT]
[image: SCHEMATIC]

Comment: can you share your simulation file? or can you post full schematic? not easy to follow in this way

Comment: "It is to my understanding as the load current decreases, the switching frequency reduces." Is related to your control system? Usually, no-load is the most difficult to handle since you get the rectified peak voltage of the transformer. My impression is that a bleeder load is an industry way of dealing with that in a quasi-resonant topology. In your HV application, a constant resistor load or on-off control is probably more viable.